# Why "Multiple definitions linker error" when nm only sees one definition

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

When linking some object files together I get a bunch of errors like:

```
obj-ia32/ShadowRoutine.o: In function `InitializeMap(unsigned int*)':
ShadowRoutine.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `InitializeMap(unsigned int*)'
obj-ia32/ShadowRoutine.o:ShadowRoutine.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

with compilation and linking commands of:

```
g++ -DBIGARRAY_MULTIPLIER=1 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fno-stack-protector \
    -DTARGET_IA32 -DHOST_IA32 -DTARGET_LINUX  -I../../../source/include/pin \
    -I../../../source/include/pin/gen -I../../../extras/components/include \
    -I../../../extras/xed-ia32/include -I../../../source/tools/InstLib -O3 \
    -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-variable \
    -Wno-unused-function -I. -Ishadow-memory -m32 -c \
    -o obj-ia32/ShadowRoutine.o ShadowRoutine.cpp
g++ -DBIGARRAY_MULTIPLIER=1 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fno-stack-protector \
    -DTARGET_IA32 -DHOST_IA32 -DTARGET_LINUX  -I../../../source/include/pin \
    -I../../../source/include/pin/gen -I../../../extras/components/include \
    -I../../../extras/xed-ia32/include -I../../../source/tools/InstLib -O3 \
    -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-variable \
    -Wno-unused-function -I. -Ishadow-memory -m32 -c \
    -o obj-ia32/Jikes.o Jikes.cpp
g++ -shared -Wl,--hash-style=sysv -Wl,-Bsymbolic \
    -Wl,--version-script=../../../source/include/pin/pintool.ver \
    -m32 -o obj-ia32/Jikes.so obj-ia32/ClientReq.o obj-ia32/Server.o \
    obj-ia32/ShadowRoutine.o obj-ia32/FncnMap.o obj-ia32/Trace.o \
    obj-ia32/Jikes.o obj-ia32/ClientReq.o obj-ia32/Server.o \
    obj-ia32/ShadowRoutine.o obj-ia32/FncnMap.o obj-ia32/Trace.o \
    -L../../../ia32/lib -L../../../ia32/lib-ext -L../../../ia32/runtime/glibc \
    -L../../../extras/xed-ia32/lib \
    -L/home/karl/r/git/pin/source/tools/Jikes/zmq/inst/lib \
    -lpin -lxed -lpindwarf -ldl -lzmq
```

The only two object files with `InitializeMap` are `Jikes.o` and `ShadowRoutine.o`:

```
$ nm obj-ia32/Jikes.o  | grep InitializeMap
         U _Z13InitializeMapPj
$ nm obj-ia32/ShadowRoutine.o | grep InitializeMap
00000000 T _Z13InitializeMapPj
$ nm obj-ia32/* | grep InitializeMap
         U _Z13InitializeMapPj
00000000 T _Z13InitializeMapPj
```

So why am I getting "multiple definitions of `InitializeMap`" if it's only "defined" in one object file and "undefined" in the only other object file that required it using `extern`?

This is what the declarations, definitions, and uses look like:

```
$ grep -r InitializeMap *
Jikes.cpp:  if (rtn_name == "sysInitializeMap") {       RTN_INSERT_1(InitializeMap);
Binary file obj-ia32/Jikes.o matches
Binary file obj-ia32/ShadowRoutine.o matches
ShadowRoutine.cpp:VOID InitializeMap(ADDRINT *smID) { init_map(*(int*)smID); }
ShadowRoutine.hpp:VOID InitializeMap(ADDRINT *smID);
```

where both the cpp files `#include "ShadowRoutine.hpp"`.

EDIT: My question is why does the linker command (the third g++ command in the second code snippet above) not work even though `nm` says that the function is only defined in the text of `ShadowRoutine.o` and *undefined* in `Jikes.o`?

Comment: Don't put definitions in headers. Only declarations. (Except class definitions and inline functions.)

Comment: @KerrekSB and templated functions/classes?

Comment: Do I not have only the declaration in the header? `ShadowRoutine.hpp:VOID InitializeMap(ADDRINT *smID);`

Comment: @Ben: There's no such thing, but indeed, templates can also be defined repeatedly. All those exceptions require that each version is identical in some sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the file `obj-ia32/ShadowRoutine.o` listed twice in your link command.

Comment: And, indeed, all the object files by the looks of it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yep - managed to include the `*.o` makefile variable in my linker command twice.